# html image not showing when in subdirectory

Tags: html, image

Small problem. I am developing a site locally. I have a folder on a remote server with images in it. For some reason I can not access these images locally or on the remote server. When i place the image in the public_html directory I can reference the image, but once I put it in a subdirectory I get a "cannot retrieve resource" message. For example on my remote server,

Not working:

```
<img src='http://example.com/media/3D/image.png'/>
```

Working:

```
<img src='http://example.com/image.png'/>
```

Also locally

Not working:

```
<img src='http://localhost/devsite/media/3D/image.png'/>
```

Working:

```
<img src='http://localhost/devsite/image.png'/>
```

I have permissions set to 777 for all folders an files within. 
When I type the URLs into a browser, the images show.
Any ideas?

EDIT

.htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^xyz\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.xyz\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/example\.com\/dev\/" [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Have you any .htaccess files on the server?

Comment: There is an .htaccess file in the public_html directory, not in the media directory. issue?

Comment: It could be, depending upon the contents of the .htaccess file.  Can you edit your original post with the contents?

Comment: ....You will never believe it. It was Ad Block Plus on Google Chrome *Face Palm*. Thank you for all your help